# Having trouble dynamically writing HTML in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Okay, so I am working on code to display all the images in a folder as a gallery. I've got a PHP script to find all the files in the folder (someone else had written it, and it works just fine):

```
<?php
$directory = $_REQUEST['folder'];
if (!is_dir($directory)) {
 exit('Invalid diretory path');
}
$files = array();
foreach (scandir($directory) as $file) {
 if ('.' === $file) continue;
 if ('..' === $file) continue;
 $files[] = $file;
}
echo json_encode($files);
?>
```

Now I had a javascript get the json from the php and display it in a grid:

```
const urlParams = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
const folder = urlParams.get('folder');
const gallery =  document.getElementById("web_gallery");

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    for(var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++)
    {
      var write = "<img src='" + folder + "/" + myObj[i] + "' id='gallery_img'>";
      console.log(write);
      gallery.innerHTML += write;
    }
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "toJson.php?folder=" + folder, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

This works just fine on Firefox, but it doesn't display anything on Chrome. I looked through several threads here and the one with the most traction seamed to suggest that I should try to use JQuery, so I set that up and wrote this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

const urlParams = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
const folder = urlParams.get('folder');
var url = "toJson.php?folder=" + folder;
var toWrite = [];

$.get(url, function( data ) {
  var images = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
  {  
    toWrite.push("<img src='" + folder + "/" + images[i] + "' id='gallery_img'>");
    //$( "#web_gallery" ).append( write ); // Had this here before, but tried to move it down to after it's done.
  }
}).done(function()
{
  for(var i = 0; i < toWrite.length; i++)
  {
    $("#web_gallery").append(toWrite[i]);
  }
});
});
```

Someone else suggested that you shouldn't do so many append requests so I changed it to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

const urlParams = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
const folder = urlParams.get('folder');
var url = "toJson.php?folder=" + folder;
var write = "";

$.get(url, function( data ) {
  var images = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
  {
    write += "<img src='" + folder + "/" + images[i] + "' id='gallery_img'>\n";
  }
}).done(function()
{
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("#web_gallery").append(write);
    }, 1500);
});
});
```

All of these work fine in Firefox, but not a single one of them work in Chrome, and I'm not sure why. It seems to have to do with the time and speed of writing to the page, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the image element with the createElement method.

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = imageFilePath;
$(image).appendTo("#web_gallery");
```